# How to use same unique_ptr in multiple classes

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

I am trying to change my current design and want to use smart pointers (preferably `unique_ptr`as **Herb Sutter** says, when in doubt, prefer `unique_ptr` by default) but I am confused which fits in my current design where one pointer will be passed to multiple classes.

The sample code is as follows

```
class X {
private:
    ZHandler* _mZHandler; //change it as unique_ptr or shared_ptr??
public:
    X()
    {
        Z* zPtr = createUsingFactory(); // instantiated by legacy code factory function, createUsingFactory() is just representational
        _mZHandler = new ZHandler(zPtr);
    }
    ~X()
    {
        delete _mZHandler;
    }
    void callYfunc()
    {
        _mZHandler->funcY();
    }
};

//ZHandler wraps the calls to Z as well as serves as event listner to Z
class ZHandler : public Z::ZEventListner {
private:
    Z* _mPtrZ; 
public:
    ZHandler(Z* ptr) : _mPtrZ(ptr){}
    void funcY()
    {
        _mPtrZ->funcZ();
    }
    void funcNotifyEvent
    {
    }
};

class Z {
private:
    ZEventListner* _mZEventListner;
public:
    class ZEventListner{
        vitual void funcNotifyEvent() = 0;
    };
    void setEventListner(ZEventListner* ptr)
    {
        _mZEventListner = ptr;
    }
    ZEventListner* getEventListner(){return _mZEventListner};
    void funcZ(){}
    void funcNotify() //called by some other class
    {
        _mZEventListner->funcNotifyEvent();
    }
};
```

The question is whether to use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` for `ZHandler` pointer in `class X`? (accordingly the functions and pointers will change in other classes),
If i use `unique_ptr` then I have to move the ptr of `ZHandler` in `setEventListner` function, and once i do that the original pointer will be lost and further calls to `ZHandler` from `X` won't be possible.

Comment: Why are you preferring `unique_ptr`? `shared_ptr` does exactly what you need it to do.

Comment: Hint: If you want the pointer to be _shared_, use the class, that has _shared_ in the name.

Comment: The semantics of a `std::unique_ptr` is to indicate _ownership_. If you need to share the objects, use `std::shared_ptr` or a raw pointer.

Comment: so many negatives even before the question is complete, @lcs, I am thinking about the efficiency too, because there will be multiple such classes present.

Comment: @Tejendra `std::unique_ptr` is not designed to be shared. It's what makes it *unique*. And that's why the standard provides `std::shared_ptr`. For when you need to share ownership.

Comment: What inefficiency are you trying to avoid? The cost of constructing another `shared_ptr` from an existing `shared_ptr` is likely on the same order as moving a `unique_ptr`

Comment: @Tejendra You cannot fault someone for commenting on your question *as it was posted*. Users assume that a question is complete when it's posted.

Comment: @Tejendra 1) "_so many negatives even before the question is complete_" Why did you post incomplete question, then? 2) "_I am thinking about the efficiency too_" Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: If `Z` doesn't own the `ZEventListener` object, use a `uniqe_ptr` in `X` and a raw pointer in `Z`.  If it does, use a `shared_ptr` both places.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, Z doesn't own the ZEventListner, it simply uses it to notify to ZHelper, the ownership actually lies with X, that means If i create unique_ptr in X and pass it as a raw pointer in Z and store as raw pointer, that way i can use `unique_ptr`, that seems an option and avoid `shared_ptr`,

Comment: Why do you think you need a smart pointer *at all* for `_mZHandler`? As it is solely owned by class `X` I would just make it a non-pointer member variable `ZHandler _mZHandler`.

Comment: @Tejendra • Herb Sutter discusses this topic in his GotW series.  https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart pointers are all about ***ownership***. That means which objects are responsible for **deleting** their members. So you should look at which objects **delete** the things they have pointers to.

If the design is such that it is impossible to know which pointer will be the last to reference an object (and hence be the one used to delete it) then you should use a `std::shared_ptr`.

If, on the other hand, there is only **one** pointer that will outlast all other references and that will always need to be the one the object is deleted through, then that should be a `std::unique_ptr`.

Most ***owning*** pointers (pointers that need to delete stuff) tend to be `std::unique_ptr`.

If you have a pointer to an object that will **always** outlive the pointer and be deleted by some other object, then you should use a ***raw pointer*** or **preferably** a ***reference***.

So you have to decide which objects in your design will **live** the longest and which objects will be responsible for destroying the objects they point to and choose your pointers accordingly.

**Shared pointer**: When you do not know which pointer will have to delete the object because you do not know which pointer will go out of scope (or be deleted) last.

**Unique pointer**: When the pointed to object will be destroyed from exactly one place and all other referees to that object will have expired before this pointer needs to delete it.

**Raw pointer/Reference**: When someone else is responsible for deleting the object because this pointer/reference's need to access the object will have expired before that happens.

Comment: In my code, the creation and deletion will solely be handled by `class X`, which was designed as raw pointer, however as both the classes use this pointer then in order to use the pointer i need to pass the ownership, don't I?, which will in turn delete the pointer from actual owner class.

Comment: @Tejendra If the object of `class X` will always live longer than the objects it passes the pointer to, then it should pass a *raw pointer* or a *reference*. If every object of `class X` will have its own `ZHandler` then either use a `std::unique_ptr`. However if more than object of `class X` need to share a `ZHandler` then you would need a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Tejendra You do **not** need to pass ownership to simply use a pointer. To simply use it, pass a raw pointer using `call_function(m_ZHandler.get());` or (better) pass a reference using `call_function(*m_ZHandler);`

Comment: that seems OK, but doesn't it break the whole concept of smart pointers? currently the library which has `class Z` is developed by me, but in future if someone else works on this then i probably need to take care that someone don't accidentally **delete** the pointer

Comment: @Tejendra No, the whole point of smart pointers is to manage the destruction of their target. They are not supposed to be passed round the system unless you also need to pass on the responsibility of destroying the target to another object. **NOBODY** should be deleting random raw pointers just because they feel like it. If anyone does that kind of thing then nothing can save you from them. But, as I said before, you can always pass a **reference** rather than a pointer. That's usually preferable.

Comment: using `unique_ptr` in conjunction with raw ptrs solves my problem, and it seems to be ok design wise too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but rather an approach to avoid being confused with the smart pointers. At first, don't use either unique_ptr or shared_ptr. Instead spend a day to learn about RAII and try implementing your own "unique_ptr" (you can take a look into the stl code). That will give you the idea how the unique_ptr works. Then try to implement your own "shared_ptr". The simplest way to implement your own shared ptr is around objects that use internal reference counting.

After you learned how they work, using either unique_ptr or shared_ptr looses it's magic and you should know which to use when.